# EntityFramework Core for MySql mapping database type Point to my own class

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table `Apartment(location: point)`.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Database first to generate my model classes.

I found that this lib doesn't provide type mapping for Point, so it skips generating the Location column every time.

My own Point class looks like:

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public int SRID { get; set; }
}
```

So, I am wondering is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You should use only one of `entity-framework` and `entity-framework-core` tags

Comment: hi @vasily.sib  could you please elaborate your idea?